# Modis image processing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a modis *tiff* image of size 2000 by 4059, with `int16` values. I want to multiply the image by scale factor of 0.0001 to get reflectance in Matlab.

Comment: You should be able to do everything you need with these functions: [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html), [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) and [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)...

Answer (score 1):

As @zplesivcak said:

```
 img = imread( 'myModisImg.tiff' ); %// img should be 2000x4059 array of type uint16
 img = im2double( img ); %// now img is of type double in the range [0..1]
 rimg = img * 0.0001; %// multiply each pixel by 0.0001
```